# Recreate selinux .te file from loaded policy

Tags: selinux

I don't have the original .te file or .mod or .pp files for a custom pp I created from audit2allow -a output.  The policy is currently running on the server and I would like to get the original te file back to I can append new audit2allow rules and just maintain one pp file.

If I cat the cli file I can see the rules but would like a way to get the .te file back.

cli file output

(typeattributeset cil_gen_require nrpe_t)
(typeattributeset cil_gen_require sudo_log_t)
(typeattributeset cil_gen_require faillog_t)
(typeattributeset cil_gen_require var_log_t)
(typeattributeset cil_gen_require initrc_var_run_t)
(allow nrpe_t faillog_t (dir (add_name write)))
(allow nrpe_t faillog_t (file (create setattr)))
(allow nrpe_t initrc_var_run_t (file (lock open read)))
(allow nrpe_t self (capability (chown dac_override)))
(allow nrpe_t sudo_log_t (file (open)))
(allow nrpe_t var_log_t (dir (write)))

Maybe this output is enough to recreate  the .te file not sure but wondering if there is a command or set of commands that can do this.

Is there a way ?

Comment: You say you can cat a file and see the rules, can you edit your question with the rules you see?